# Get Big Double Value As Plain Decimal Format In Java

Tags: java, double, precision, number-formatting

I am developing an Accounting Management Application where I need to store information about transactions. As amount or total amount of transaction may cross a 17 digits number, I want them to show in plain text or plain `Decimal` format. But in `Java` a big number shows as Exponential format. I have searched for it on `Google` and `Stackoverflow` for solution, but did not get any suitable one. I have tried these:

```
    double number = 123456789123456789.987654;

    System.out.println("" + number);

    System.out.println(number);

    System.out.println(String.format("%.3f", number));

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
    System.out.println(df.format(number));

    DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    System.out.println(df1.format(number));

    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(number).stripTrailingZeros().setScale(3));
```

And the outputs are:

```
1.23456789123456784E17
1.23456789123456784E17
123456789123456784.000
123456789123456784
123456789123456784
123456789123456784.000
```

I want the output as **`123456789123456789.988`**

How can I get output like that?

Comment: **NEVER use a floating point type to store money amounts**. Due to its internal representation, they trade the range of number they can represent by the possibility of rounding errors. Use integer formats (`int` or `long`), or classes that provide exact precission (like `BigDecimal`). If you have fractional money (cents), you can use int or long by counting cents instead of the currency unit (and dividing by 100 when you want to represent it).

Comment: Hint: In the last line, use `new BigDecimal("123456789123456789.987654")` Note that by avoiding the conversion to double you avoid the loss of precission.

Comment: But my client can provide floating point type value, and they want to store those. In addition, during calculation, it may provide a floating type data. In that case what can I do? I tried to convince them, but they want to see transactions like that :(

Comment: Value you assigned to number variable is so big that double data type  can not handle it. if you try your test cases with say 12345678912345.987654 everything will work fine. Hence you can not rely on double for your requirement.

Comment: `new BigDecimal("123456789123456789.987654")` returning me perfect result, but I have to retrieve it mostly from database. In that case it's providing me this `123456789123456784`

Comment: @NinadShaha : In that case what can I use?

Comment: Explain the issue to your customer, with this code (and my version) and its outputs. If your customer insist in using floats or doubles, as soon as you read one you convert it to BigDecimal and operate with those.

Comment: That's a very good idea, operate with `BigDecimal`